# Getting an unresolved reference: FirebaseError

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

Here is my code:

```
override fun onCancelled(firebaseError: FirebaseError) {}
```

I am getting `unresolved reference: FirebaseError`

I am importing:

```
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener
```

Here's the full code:

```
usernameDatabase.child(username).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.exists()) {
                        // TODO: handle the case where the data already exists
                    } else {
                        // TODO: handle the case where the data does not yet exist
                    }
                }

                override fun onCancelled(firebaseError: FirebaseError) {}
            })
```

This is written in Kotlin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change `FirebaseError` to `DatabaseError`. And make sure that auto-import is enabled.

Then your problem will be eradicated!